# `Execution timeout` when setting video’s content?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm setting

`m.top.video.content = invalid`

And the debugger pauses on this line, saying:

---

"Rendezvous aborted for myTask

...

Execution timeout"

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding the issue? There seems to be a Task involved in the cause of the problem. Some additional code/logic behind it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information about this code.

Firstly, if you are setting the content in a task, at what point in the tasks lifecycle are you setting this?

Secondly, can you confirm that the video object itself is not invalid?

Also, why are you setting content to invalid?